# How to specify regex quantifiers with mawk?

Tags: regular-expression, mawk

I'm familiar with the concept of specified bounded regex quantifiers as follows:

```
Quantifier  Legend               Example    Sample Match

{3}         Exactly three times  \D{3}      ABC
{2,4}       Two to four times    \d{2,4}    156
{3,}        Three or more times  \w{3,}     regex_tutorialer
```

However, I've not been able to find anything like the above for `mawk` in the man pages nor online.

Does the `mawk` command have this functionality, or is there a different way of accomplishing the same effect?

I am using version `1.3.3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interval regexp operators are supported in POSIX compliant `awk` implementations.

But as `awk` initially didn't support them (neither did nawk nor mawk nor gawk), there are still several implementations that don't support them like [`mawk`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/original-mawk/issues/25), the *one true awk* (originally maintained by Brian Kernighan, the `k` in `awk`) until [a few days ago](https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/commit/4bc685f70132a7370eb3ac27407cbce976aa1a13), Solaris `/bin/awk`, Solaris `/bin/nawk`, the `awk` of most BSDs.

Like for `egrep`, several implementations objected to adding support for them as they would break backward compatibility (there was no similar problem for `\{x,y\}` in BREs as used by `grep`).

`\w`, `\d`, `\D` are perl regexp extensions which are generally not supported (busybox `awk` and `gawk` (when not in POSIX mode) support `\w`). The standard equivalents would be `[[:alnum:]_]`, `[[:digit:]]`, `[^[:digit:]]` respectively, but are not supported by `mawk` yet¹.

On Solaris, you'll want to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

With older versions of GNU `awk`, you had to use the `--re-interval` option, or start it with `POSIXLY_CORRECT=anything` in the environment for the regex intervals to be supported.

With implementation that don't support them, you can use combinations of `?`, `+` and `*`:

- `x{1,3}` -> `xx?x?` or `(x|xx|xxx)`
- `x{1,}` -> `x+`
- `x{0,}` -> `x*`
- `x{3,}` -> `xxx+` or `xxxx*`
- `x{3,6}` -> `xxxx?x?x?`
- etc.

---

<sup>¹ anyway, `mawk` doesn't support localisation or multi-byte characters, so you might as well restrict to ASCII characters and use `[_a-zA-Z]`, `[0-9]` and `[^0-9]`</sup>